# Selecting all P tags in a div imacros

Tags: imacros

Good evening everyone,

Since today i'm busy with iMacros and everything is going fine but i need to get all the 'P' tags from a div. Currently he's only getting the first Paragraph of the post.

I need to extract the text from a wordpress website and i saw that the paragraphs are inside this div:

```
<div class="post" id="post-4828">
```

I've tried a lot but nothing works.

Here is an example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

I saw that the text is within:

```
<p style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this was posted on February, but however for anyone else looking the answer would be:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:post
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

I took me a while to figure it out myself

In the case of the Edit (so the P has a style) the solution than would be:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=STYLE:"outline: 1px solid blue" EXTRACT=TXT
```